# How can I update my existing lambda(not created by cloudformation) through cloudformation. Setting up the pipeline through cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, pipeline

I am setting up the pipeline which is using the cloud formation stack by creating a changeset and executing the changeset. But the first time this creates another lambda and does not have a way to update or deploy the existing created lambda.

**buildspec.yml**

```
version: 0.1
phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - echo "nothing to do in install phase"
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - mvn clean install
  build:
    commands:
      - aws cloudformation package --template-file samTemplate.yaml --s3-bucket saurabh-lambda-pipeline --output-template-file outputSamTemplate.yaml
artifacts:
  type: zip
  files:
    - samTemplate.yaml
    - outputSamTemplate.yaml
```

**samTemplate.yaml**

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Description: CD Lambda
Resources:
  testLambda:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: testLambda
      Handler: com.test.handler.calculator::handleRequest
      Runtime: java8
      CodeUri: target/emi-calculator.jar
      AutoPublishAlias: prod
      Description: 'Lambda function for CD'
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 30
      Events:
        getAZsAPI:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /calculator
            Method: post
      Environment:
        Variables:
          calculatorType: 30
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add existing resources to a existing cloud formation stack. AWS Console > Cloudformation > Open your Stack > Actions > Import existing resources.
https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/aws/new-import-existing-resources-into-a-cloudformation-stack/
Then compare your local cloudformation template with the one on in CloudFormation.

Comment: Thanks for that, but how do I integrate this with pipeline. Since this for this i need to specify Code property in template file which will be static, but I want my cloudformation template to be generated from pipeline with above samTemplate.yaml